# How to get response from another PHP file that is called by form post

Tags: php, forms, file, post, server

I have form that calls php file like this (contact.php):

```
<form role="form" id="form1" method="post" class="validate" action="contact_actions.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

contact_actions.php at the end calls back `header('Location: contact.php');`

I am a noob regarding php and having hard time finding exact example that will show me how to get some response from contact_actions.php, like error message or succeeded message... I've found some complicated solutions, but I am wondering is there some simple one with maybe global variable? I've tried with global variables and it didn't work, maybe with wrong ones and maybe in a wrong way. Also, what is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Put code from contact_actions.php in a function.
- This function can return true or false, and even fill an &$error
  parameter.
- Remove contact_actions.php
- Change form action to contact.php
- Inside contact.php, call that function, and show info according to
  its result.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use global variables, they're not useful and bad style.

Use $_GET.

Like:

```
header('Location: contact.php?success=1');
```

Then in contact.php

```
if ($_GET['success'] == 1) {
  echo "The contact-form has been sent";
}
```

Comment: `$_GET` *is* a (super)global variable... maybe clarify what you mean with "don't use global variables"

Comment: I particularly don't fancy to glue my internal things onto URL, we also don't want user copying that URL and giving it to others or refreshing page and getting same message all over again without going through the process. My policy is; hide as much from the user as possible, user should not be concerned with my internal workings. It's logical to me that when you are on the server and doing processing of PHP files, that they could communicate without friction. If it's logically possible and it's more convenient, they yes, why not.

Comment: Global variables are maybe bad style, but they're useful, sure.
However, solution from @jonas3344 is a well known practice, it has some contras as Hove says, but it works. My own solution is to merge contact_actions.php and contact.php, using a function to do the mail sending.

Comment: Yeah, with don't use global variables I meant:

global $var;